# Finding Max of dates in SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

| CType | Material | CoCd | Plnt | SOrg | SoldTo | ShipTo | Customer | Vendor | SerProv | POrg | Year | per | UoM | NSapRel | Amount | Crcy | ChangedOn | Time | Changedby | SAPdate | SAPTime | SAPUser |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PB00 | 775515 | 100 | GA |  |  |  |  | 7500000678 |  | PO04 | 2022 | 100 | CAS |  | 9,299.36 | BRL | 15.02.2022 | 13:55:16 | User1 | 15.02.2022 | 13:56:15 | User1 |
| PB00 | 775515 | 100 | GA |  |  |  |  | 7500000678 |  | PO04 | 2022 | 100 | CAS |  | 5,907.42 | BRL | 28.01.2022 | 18:45:45 |  | 02.02.2022 | 12:32:18 | SAPPO_DEP_AZ |

I have written a query for the above table, to get max date of these two rows, Unfortunately, it returns as '28.01.2022' every time.

Here is my query.

```
SELECT
       CType,
       Material,
       CoCd,
       Plnt,
       [Customer],
       SOrg,
       [Vendor],
       max_date = MAX(ChangedOn) OVER (
          PARTITION BY
              CType,
              Material,
              CoCd,
              Plnt,
              [Customer],
              SOrg,
              [Vendor]) 
FROM
      Calc
WHERE
          CType='PB00'
      AND
          Material='775515'
      AND
          Plnt='GA'
```

Expected output: for MAxDate column is '15.02.2022'

All columns in Varchar(500), so I tried following query as well,

```
SELECT
       CType,
       Material,
       CoCd,
       Plnt,
       [Customer],
       SOrg,
       [Vendor],
       MAX(cast(ltrim(rtrim(ChangedOn)) as date)) AS max_date
FROM
       Calc
WHERE
          CType='PB00'
   AND
          Material='775515'
   AND
          Plnt='GA'
GROUP BY
          CType,
          Material,
          CoCd,
          Plnt,
          [Customer],
          SOrg,
          [Vendor]
```

Showing error 'Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.'

Is anything wrong here?

Comment: What type is your `ChangedOn` column?

Comment: Everything is varchar(500)

Comment: First of all, please provide consumable sample data instead of Screenshots.
Concerning your query: Is there any reason why you use the window function instead of a regular group by? Following an eexample:

    `SELECT CType,Material, CoCd, Plnt,  [Customer], SOrg, [Vendor], MAX(ChangedOn) AS max_date
    FROM Calc
    WHERE CType='PB00'
      AND Material='775515'
      AND Plnt='GA'
    GROUP BY CType,Material, CoCd, Plnt,  [Customer], SOrg, [Vendor]`

However you will have to convert the ChangedOn to date in orderfor this to work.

Comment: "Everything is varchar(500) " - That would be your answer. `VARCHAR` is not a date, therefore "28.01" is more than "15.02"

Comment: I took the time to edit your question, imagining that you wanted to make the question easy to read and therefore answer.

Comment: By not storing dates as `date` any operations that require SQL Server to unpack what the actual date value is becomes unsargable and you force a full index or table scan every time. Dates are *not* text!

Comment: As a separate note, you *really* need to get your SQL Server upgrade path implemented; SQL Server 2008 R2 ran out of support well over 3 years ago now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `CONVERT` or `TRY_CONVERT` function to convert the varchar date to date datatype inside the max function, But it would be better to store date values as a date to avoid such problems.

Try the following:

```
SELECT CType,Material, CoCd, Plnt,  [Customer], SOrg, [Vendor],
       max_date = MAX(TRY_CONVERT(DATE, ChangedOn, 104)) OVER 
       (PARTITION BY CType,Material, CoCd, Plnt, [Customer], SOrg, [Vendor])    
FROM Calc where CType='PB00' and Material='775515' and Plnt='GA'
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/cHx0c0YZ).